# Ni-Fi. Как сделать несколько запросов в одной транзакции PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, apache

Есть 2 PutSQL. Первый создаёт временную таблицу (CREATE TABLE qwe (...) ON COMMIT DROP). Второй вставляет в это таблицу записи. В обоих процессорах Database Session AutoCommit установлен в false, настроен одинаковый DBCPConnectionService с одним единственным подключением, Support Fragmented Transactions установлен в false. Но при этом второй процессор бросает исключения, говоря, что "relation 'qwe' does not exist". Как настроить процессоры так, чтобы они работали в рамках одной транзакции?

```
    BEGIN;

    -- Первый PutSQL выполняет запрос на создание.
    CREATE TEMP TABLE qwe(
      id int,
      name varchar(50)
    ) ON COMMIT DROP;
    -- Конец работы первого PutSQL.

    -- Второй PutSQL вставляет записи, но выбрасывает ошибку, "relation 'qwr' does not exists".
    INSERT INTO qwe values(1, '123');
    INSERT INTO qwe values(2, '1');
    INSERT INTO qwe values(3, '2');
    INSERT INTO qwe values(4, '2');
    INSERT INTO qwe values(5, '4');
    INSERT INTO qwe values(6, '523');

    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Залез в исходники и обнаружил интересный метод:

```
    public void constructProcess() {
    /* Код опущен */

    process.onCompleted((c, s, fc, conn) -> {
        try {
            conn.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Throw ProcessException to rollback process session.
            throw new ProcessException("Failed to commit database connection due to " + e, e);
        }
    });

    /* Код опущен */
}
```

Судя по всему, при трансфере файла в следующий процессор происходит коммит изменений в базе данный, и временная таблица (ON COMMIT DROP) удаляется. Видимо без костылей не обойтись.
Начало метода - 540 строка: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/PutSQL.java (надеюсь я не нарушил законы)

Answer (score 0):

1. Временная таблица создаётся в рамках сессии.
2. Два разных соединения, это разные сессии и никак в рамках одной транзакции их не выполнить.

Comment: В Ni-Fi за создания подключений отвечает **DBCPConnectionPool**, а PutSQL только берёт уже готовое подключение. У меня пул настроен так, что в нём есть только одно подключение и оно никогда не прерывается, поэтому я считал, что смогу в разных процессорах работать с одной и той же временной таблицей. Но после дайвинга в исходники я понял, что ошибался.